# How double or unexpected character remove from UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on UITextField and its delegate. If I use two text fields I can easily resign first text field and also go to second text field. But when I empty the second text field that means when character range is zero I can go to first text field. But when I press the return key then resign first text field and go to second text field. But there is a problem when I want to write here extra one character add to it. below is my code

```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if (textField.tag == 0) {
    firstTextLabel.text = newString;
}else if(textField.tag == 1){
    if([textField.text.length] == 0){
       [secondTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
       [firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    secondTextLabel.text = newString;
}
return YES;
```

}

```
     - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

if (textField.tag == 0) {
    [firstTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}else if(textField.tag == 1){
    [secondTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [thirdTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
```

}

Comment: So what is the problem you encounter?

Comment: extra one character add to the secondtextField. when i press return button

Answer (score 2):

Please read the docu for NSResponder.becomeFirstResponder:

> Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are setting `firstTextLabel.text = newString;` and then you `return YES` at the end of the code.

You have to options

- Delete the `return YES;` at the end of `textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`
- Follow this full guide (**I recommend this option)**:

  - **First of all**,

  Whenver you set `becomeFirstResponder` , `resignFirstResponder` It is not necessary.

  So delete all `resignFirstResponder`

  - **Second:**
    If you have multiple text fields, for example 100 textfields, all with tag from 1 to 100,
    here is a code I made to handle who becomes first responder.

    ```
     - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
     {

           NSInteger tag = textField.tag;
           UITextField *nextTextfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag+1];
           [nextTextfield becomeFirstResponder];

         return NO;

     }
    ```
  - **Third:**
    Change:

    ```
     if (textField.tag == 0) {
         firstTextLabel.text = newString; }
    ```

    To:

    ```
     if (textField.tag == 0) {
         return YES; }
    ```
  - **Fourth**

    Change:

    ```
     -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

     NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
     if (textField.tag == 0) {
         firstTextLabel.text = newString;
     }else if(textField.tag == 1){
         if([textField.text.length] == 0){
            [secondTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
            [firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
         }
         secondTextLabel.text = newString;
     }
     return YES;
    ```

    To:

    ```
     -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

     NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

      if(textField.tag == 1){
         if([textField.text.length] == 0){
            [firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
         }
         return YES;
      }
     return YES;
    ```

If you have any questions feel free to ask.